# Use function to return a modified string

Tags: c, string

**N**-number

**s**-string

**C**-character

Depending on the inputed number **N**, rewrite the given string **s**.

If **N**>0 use the character **C** and attach it **N** times to the end of **s**.

If **N**<0 remove every non-letter and non-digit character from the string **s**.

I wrote the comments to help with navigation. For N>0 it does what it should plus some weird characters(so not). For N<0 nothing happens.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* stinger(char*,char,int);
int main()
{
    char s[20],C;
    int N;
    puts("Enter the string: ");
    gets(s);
    puts("Enter the char: ");
    scanf("%c",&C);
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    //finished inputing the arguments


    printf("%s",stinger(s,C,N));
    /*calling the created function inside main()
    hoping it would return me a string that fulfills the conditions*/
}
char* stinger(char*s,char C,int N){
char T[20],G[20];
int i,k=0;

if (N>0){
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        T[i]=C;
    //here I've created a string that should attach to the end
    return strcat(s,T);
}
else if (N<0){
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
        if((s[i]>='A'&&s[i]<='Z')||(s[i]>='a'&&s[i]<='z')||(s[i]>='0'&&s[i]<='9')){
            G[k++]=s[i];
        }
        }
    return G;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should use **fgets(s,20,stdin);** instead of gets.

Comment: `return G;` return local variable.

Comment: I think @BLUEPIXY called it. Another point, look up isalnum(3) instead of your lengthy conditional (which may not work, depending on character set).

Comment: Because of your missing brackets i don't understand the whole code, you can start from [here](http://ideone.com/khptCe). Any way don't forget to free that pointer.

Comment: @Michi here it makes things worse.

Comment: @Desperado please explain.

Comment: @Michi string T doesn't connect properly, it goes into a new line

Comment: there is a '\0' missing in both for :) check [This](http://ideone.com/LqVltJ)

Comment: I've just figured out that I had no idea how to create a string manually, until now. First link works for the N>0, second for the N<0. I will figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code

1) you need to null-terminate your strings

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++) T[i]=C;
T[i] = '\0' // you forgot this

for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
   if(isalnum(s[i])) G[k++]=s[i];
G[k]= '\0'; // again, terminate the string with 0
```

2) second error is, `return G`... but G has lost scope after you return from the function, because the array G is *local* to the function `stinger`. What you could do is create the array to hold the result in the caller function and pass it as a pointer to the called function.

Answer (score 0):

1. `G` is a variable which is accessible only to stringer function and you are returning it to the same function.

gets()

This is bad because it can overflow the input string buffer. For example, if the buffer size is 2, and you enter in 16 characters, you will overflow str.

fgets()

This is safe because you can guarantee you never overflow the input string buffer by passing in the buffer size (which includes room for the NULL.)